# Элементы массива не выводятся из объекта при нажатии на клавишу

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на клавишу 0 в поле инпута должно появиться число 0, но этого не происходит.

```js
var calc = {
  numbers: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  plus: function(){
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
      if(event.keyCode == 48) {
        document.getElementById('field').value = this.numbers[0];
      }
    })
  }
}
calc.plus();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Вы в обработчике обращаетесь к `this`, хотя в нем `this` указывает на элемент у которого произошло событие
- Вы вешаете обработчик `keypress` не на инпут, а на весь документ
- Если не отменить возникшее событие вызовом `event.preventDefault()`, то вначале Вы присвоете инпуту значение, а потом в него же добавится текущая клавиша.

Итого:

```js
var calc = {
  numbers: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  plus: function() {
    var thisCalc = this;
    document.getElementById('field').addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 48) {
        this.value = thisCalc.numbers[0];
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  }
}
calc.plus();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field">
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам надо сохранить контекст объекта calc, так как `document.addEventListener('keypress', function(){` тут он теряется

```js
var calc = {
  numbers: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  plus: function(){
    var that = this;
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
      if(event.keyCode == 48) {
        document.getElementById('field').value = that.numbers[0];
      }
    })
  }
}
calc.plus();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field">
```

Answer (score 3):

Второй вариант с функцией-стрелочкой:

```js
var calc = {
  numbers: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  plus: function(){
    document.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
      if(event.keyCode == 48) {
        document.getElementById('field').value = this.numbers[0];
      }
    })
  }
}
calc.plus();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field">
```